# How to use hyperlinks in a page to toggle for more information using Dreamweaver?

Tags: class, html, toggle, muse

I'm trying to use the toggle feature to open up more information. How do you use hyperlinks in a webpage to just open up a toggle feature that located elsewhere on the page for more information? The hyperlink should not go to a different page and also, the page was created using Adobe Muse, which created div classs and divs, so where can I paste the code into the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hyperlink to execute a javascript function without going to another page.

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('test'); return false">Test</a>
```

Replace the alert with the javascript function that does your toggle functionality.